# Plugin Cost Calculator no se muestra

Tags: wordpress, plugin

tengo un problema con el Plugin Cost Calculator, aunque coloco el shortcode del formulario en la página, cuando lo publico no se ve nada, aunque si está allí no se muestra:

`https://socialmonkeyagencia.com/prueba-cost-calculator/`

Como ven en el espacio en blanco si está el formulario pero sale todo en blanco no tengo idea por qué. Saludos y gracias

---

No se ve absolutamente nada, Al parecer es el navegador, uso chrome, lo acabo de probar en edge y si lo puedo ver bien. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Disculpa, hace tiempo ya que no juego con WP. ¿Qué es lo que debería mirar? Veo un formulario que calcula un costo abajo a medida que muevo cosas

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, deberías ver algo como esto: http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/cost-calculator-wordpress-plugin/full_screen_preview/12778927 sin embargo cuando aplico el shortcode en mi página ese formulario si está allí solo que no se muestra, está todo en blanco. Y no entiendo por qué. Gracias

Comment: Esto es un comentario pero necesito ponerte la imagen. No sé qué es lo que sale diferente (más allá de que en uno le hice click a next y en el otro no, pero en ambos probé diligenciar el formulario y sale lo mismo) [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcX4H.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcX4H.png)

Comment: Woao! A mi no me sale eso, me sale absolutamente en blanco en mi página, o no en mi página, al menos en mi pc, ahora si no tengo ni la menor idea de qué pueda estar pasando... No entiendo por qué tu lo puedes ver y yo no, como te digo me sale todo en blanco.